# How can a local variable be assigned in previous iteration of loop

Tags: loops, rust, move

Just a question so I can better understand Rust.

Why does this fail:

```
for event in rulesengine::RuleEvent::into_enum_iter()
{
  let mut event_stats: payloads::EventStats;
  event_stats.name = rulesengine::RuleEvent::to_string(&event);
  event_stats.event_count = event_counters.event_count[event as usize];
  event_stats.event_participant_count = event_counters.event_participant_count[event as usize];
  event_stats.event_trigger_count = event_counters.event_trigger_count[event as usize];
  rules_stats.event_stats.push(event_stats);
}
```

With:

```
error[E0382]: assign to part of moved value: `event_stats`
   --> src/motion.rs:317:37
    |
316 | ...                       let mut event_stats: payloads::EventStats;
    |                               --------------- move occurs because `event_stats` has type `payloads::EventStats`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
317 | ...                       event_stats.name = rulesengine::RuleEvent::to_string(&event).clone();
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value partially assigned here after move
...
323 | ...                   },
    |                       - value moved here, in previous iteration of loop

error: aborting due to previous error
```

When this works:

```
for event in rulesengine::RuleEvent::into_enum_iter()
{
  let name = rulesengine::RuleEvent::to_string(&event);
  let event_count = event_counters.event_count[event as usize];
  let event_participant_count = event_counters.event_participant_count[event as usize];
  let event_trigger_count = event_counters.event_trigger_count[event as usize];
  let event_stats = payloads::EventStats { name, event_count, event_participant_count, event_trigger_count };
  rules_stats.event_stats.push(event_stats);
}
```

or even better

```
for event in rulesengine::RuleEvent::into_enum_iter()
{
  let event_stats = payloads::EventStats
  {
    name: rulesengine::RuleEvent::to_string(&event),
    event_count: event_counters.event_count[event as usize],
    event_participant_count: event_counters.event_participant_count[event as usize],
    event_trigger_count: event_counters.event_trigger_count[event as usize],
  };
  rules_stats.event_stats.push(event_stats);
}
```

The variable event_stats is mutable yes, but local. It doesn't exist in the "previous iteration of loop" to be moved.

Comment: Is that the right code? Why does the error message say line 323 is `},`? I don't see a `},` line above.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to simplify a bit. I should have just created a new program to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is a mis-diagnosis of the problem. There have been [compiler bugs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72649) in the past where the message incorrectly blames the loop for uninitialized variables. Perhaps this is another one of those cases.

---

The core issue is you are trying to assign a field to an uninitialized value:

```
let mut event_stats: payloads::EventStats;
event_stats.name = ...;
```

You have *declared* `event_stats` but have not *initialized* it. Rust does not allow you to piece-wise initialize a struct, at least not without [a lot of extra juggling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-a-struct-field-by-field).

Both your working solutions create `event_stats` from a struct literal:

```
let event_stats = payloads::EventStats { name: ..., ... };
```

which is the correct way to initialize a struct.